# comunicate between 2 IOS devices - how?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, bluetooth

I want to creat an app that talks with other devices.
The app is for IOS 5 and up using Objective-C
I want to be able to send data between 2 IOS devices directly (not with a server or somthing).
How can I acomplish this?

Some say Bluetooth but it is very general..
Some say GameKit but I could not find any tutorial for GameKit since IOS 3 (and even then I found only 1 guide).

Can you help me understand which technology to use and maybe direct me to tutorials that explain all of it?

The data I want to send is short string \ 2 digits int's every couple of minutes.

Thanks,
Gal

Comment: Bluetooth would probably be the appropriate route for you. There are many example on how to implement this.  Simple google 'ios Bluetooth example'.

Comment: when iOS7 is out you can use AirDrop.

Comment: Yea, unless you have good reasons for supporing iOS backwards to version 5, you may really want to wait for iOS 7. AirDrop is made for that and will ease your task significantly. In terms of timing you could be one of the first issuing a native iOS 7 app that makes advantage of this new feature.

Comment: I thought about it, and I have to support IOS6 and up at least! that is because airdrop is not aplicable for iphone 4 / 4S and I dont want to limit my app for iphone 5 only..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be something for you: 
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/bluetooth-connectivity-with-gamekit/

As you mentioned. Using bluetooth with GameKit framework is the way to go.
You can use Peer-To-Peer setup and that means no server is required.